# Laravel6.* image in laravel/public/image/xxx isn't recognized as a url

Tags: laravel, windows, laravel-6, mdbootstrap

I'm a laravel beginner and faced to simple problem. I wanna set background-image with MDBootstrap on a register blade then created the blade in  *laravel /resources/view/auth/register.blade.php* ,and corded `<div class="bg-image" style=" background-image: url('/laravel/public/image/xxx(relative path)'); " >`
And I downloaded a pic for background from free site, put it in *laravel/public/image/xxx*(relative path).

But somehow picture path doesn't work, the pic isn't recognized as a picture (underline doesn't appear) therefore can't click with Ctrl. Of course I can see the pic as I paste on the editor and Chrome. Path should be correct because I didn't type directly.

What I tried to solve,

- went to  `webpac.mix.js` and wrote `.options({processCssUrls: false});`
- replaced the image directry just under the laravel directory

but those solution didn't work well...  Make sure, my HTML and CSS code works right, since when I copy & pasted other picture url from MDB tutorial, it went well.

Does anyone let me know what is wrong and how should I work on ??

[here is a screenshot shows my blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwXXH.png)

Comment: If you saving it under public folder, then you can start your path with `/image/xxx(relative path)`

Comment: Does the file exist and can you paste its url and see the actual image? Or does the image not show up because maybe the div isn't visible? How do you serve your project? Apache, nginx, `php artisan serve`?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the `asset()` helper.

This gives you the path to assets stored in the public folder (or folder configured as your asset storage, `/public` by default).

```
<div class="bg-image" style=" background-image:{{ asset('image/xxx/' . $relative_path) }}; " >
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answering! I looked into assets() and wrote it down  following your advice, but... sorry, I can't solve this problem :(

Comment: `<div class="bg-image"
style="
 background-image:{{ asset('images\wild-geese-3379677_1920.jpg') }};
 " >`


Here is what I wrote down. I created asssets directory under public directory, then replaced images & the pic.

Comment: You don't need the assets directory in the public folder. The `asset()` helper will resolve to the public path and then you just need to give the rest of the path relative to the `public` folder. So `asset('img.jpg')` would return the file `public/img.jpg`

Comment: @とりとーり Not sure why you are suddenly using \ instead of /

Comment: I understand. Then I removed assets directory and put images & the img just under the public folder. However...I couldn't solve. 


・Once I bet I didn't define asset on app.blade.php, but probably that's not cause.

・Tried to change the code in the blade, from /images/xxx & /img/xxx.

・Also tried to change directory's name, from images to img.

Comment: I think you may need to do a little investigation. Start by looking for the image via your browser. You should find the image in the public folder using `http(s)://hostname.domain/img.jpg` (filling in the correct names). Then try outputting the result of `asset(img.jpg)` in `dd()` or return from a controller. The output should match the url in the browser. From there you should be able to get the relative path right.

Comment: New Bee 1 may have picked up on the missing element here. You may need to run `php artisan storage:link`. The Laravel install should run that when installing but you may not have installed that way. If that fixes it you should mark New Bee 1 as the right answer.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting detail solving way... I'll look into.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

first run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and
`background-image:{{ asset('image/filename') }}`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Following your tips I ran the codes, but circumstances don’t go well  I literally have no idea...